# Manipulating your angular page in a function, how can you transfer the object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to transfer my "vm" to a function and then manipulate the fields there?  (the reason I want to do that is that my controller is getting really long)

I tried but I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reportName' of undefined at modifyTheForm (index.js:163)
```

Here is the code:

```
app.controller("reportFormController", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, ReportData) {
    var vm = this;

    //
    // Change the fields
    //
    $scope.modifyForm = function () {
        console.log('reportName ' + vm.reportName)
        modifyTheForm(vm);
        console.log('reportName ' + vm.reportName)
    }

}

function modifyTheForm(myObj) {
    myObj.reportName = "CHANGED!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that , i would recommend you to do it inside the controller itself,

```
$scope.modifyForm = function () {
      vm.reportName = "CHANGED!";
}
```

Comment: Ahhh darn! - my controller is gonna be huuuge :)  Too bad thou,

Comment: You need to break into functions